# What's the best way to work with lots of buttons in a PyQt GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am working on a control interface for some I2C hardware, and my Python GUI (shown below) consists of a large array of buttons that create 8-bit commands that get sent to the device. (the chip we're using can turn 8 different outputs on and off depending on which bits are high in the signal, so as crazy as it looks, it works well for its purpose).

The aim is for each row of buttons to create a byte (selected for 1, deselected for 0) and put the result in the row's text box. I manually put an example of this in the image below. I know some very inefficient ways of doing this, but they all would require a nightmarish amount of code. Are there any more efficient ways to accomplish this?

Also, I should note that I made the Ui in Qt Designer.
[image: PYQT GUI]

Comment: I think that end user are technical specialist. so you can use numbers instead of checkbuttons. dont waste your time.
But if you are serious: try to create custom widget(inherited from qwidget) with 8 checkboxes and textfield. And reuse it.

Comment: You could use a QTableWidget and put checkboxes into the cells.